# How to add checkbox to jquery datatables with Tapestry?

Tags: jquery, datatables, tapestry

With the 'grid', I'm able to add a checkbox, but not with the 'jquery/datatable'.

I have an error : Failure writing parameter 'value' of component packetList:checkbutton: Property 'packet' (within property expression 'packet.checked', of net.rmd.mpi.pages.clients.SubpacketList@1c1101e) is null.

How to use checkbox with jquery/datatable with Tapestry ?

Thank you !

Comment: Have you actually read the error message? It sounds pretty clear to me what's wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the problem. Can you explain to me ?

Comment: Tapestry is trying to call getPacket().setChecked(...) but getPacket() is null.

Comment: The probleme is that no, getPacket() is not null...

Comment: Are you sure? I'm not talking about when the page is being rendered for view. I'm talking about when the form is posted and tapestry is trying to populate the model from the request.

Comment: Ok. So no I'm not sure. How solve this problem ? I set the boolean to false in the constructor, but it is the same

Comment: Well... with no code, you're lucky I've gotten this far :) It's impossible to help any further without code